# Remove the underline from Hyperlinked Image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, underline

It all started out with these two codes

```
            #Header .Logo   
                  {                
            background: url('http://s24.postimg.org/69nibdvz9/Header_P     .png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
            height: 186px;
            width: 100%;
            position:relative;
            top: 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px -5px;
            clear: both;
```

and

```
             <div class="Logo"><center><img src="http://s1.postimg.org/g6dji2wfj/Logo.png" style="position: relative; top: 50px;" width="640" height="160" alt="{SourceTitle}" /></center>
            </div>
```

Basically I have a header and the logo of my website on top of it. Since I'm using a logo instead of a title I wanted the image to have a link. So I added:

```
             <div class="Logo"><center> <a href="http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com"><img src="http://s1.postimg.org/g6dji2wfj/Logo.png" style="position: relative; top: 50px;" width="640" height="160" alt="{SourceTitle}" /></a></center>
            </div>
```

Now the problem is the underline that has been created by the link is ugly. How do I remove it? I tried adding the "style="text-decoration:none;" both in .Logo and in the  itself, but it made no difference. Any help?

Comment: [`<center>` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Please don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add this line of css so that any images within a link do not show borders or underline.

```
.Logo a,.Logo a img{
border:none;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Also as a side note, unless you have multiple logos you should probably use ID instead of CLASS as a best practice. You only use classes in css when there is the potential to have multiple elements needing the same styles.

Therefore making the code:

```
#Logo a, #Logo a img{
border:none;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.Logo:link, a.Logo:visited {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is putting a border around the image.

add the border property to the image style

```
<img src="http://s1.postimg.org/g6dji2wfj/Logo.png" style="position: relative; top: 50px; border: none;" width="640" height="160" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGJ4N/1/)

Answer (score 0):

if you style your link with css the line should go away

```
a:link {color:#;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#;}  /* selected link */
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp